# Обработка запросов к изображению

Tags: php

Можно ли как-нибудь обрабатывать запросы отсылаемые у изображению? Видел как это делают снифферы и прочая хакерская ересь. Например, `site/image.gif` и по нему как то читают

Comment: Вообще не ясно о чем вопрос.

Comment: Перенаправляют все запросы на скрипт, вот и все.

Comment: @Etki а как именно?

Comment: Конфигурацией того сервера, где сидит эксплоит.

Comment: То есть через .htaccess?

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете обрабатывать запросы к вашим изображениям с помощью .htaccess примерно так-

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://([^.]+.)?site. [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/image.php$
RewriteRule .(gif|jpg|png)$ /image.php [NC,L]
```

не забудьте отдавать правильные хедеры.